# Perl CGI with HTTP Status Codes in RESTful api

Tags: perl, rest, http-headers, cgi, http-status-codes

I have the following validation in a CGI script that will check for the GET method and return a 405 HTTP status code if the GET method is not used. Unfortunately it is still returning a 200 Status OK when using POST or PUT.

```
my ($buffer);
# Read in text
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "GET")
  {
$buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
  }
else
 {
  print $cgi->header(
    -type=>'text/plain',
    -status=> '405 Method Not Allowed'
  );
 }
```

but when i use LWP at client and print status_code it still gives 200 OK and when i print content it is printing the Status: 405

code i am using at Client:

```
use LWP;
use HTTP:Request::Common;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req =PUT("/path/to/request");

my $result = $ua->request($req);

if($result->is_success) {
  print "HTTP RESPONSE CODE:" , $result->status_line;
  print $result->decoded_content;
}
```

from above code it prints the following information on success

```
 HTTP RESPONSE CODE: 200 OK
 Status: 405 Method Not Allowed
 "some text regarding why method not allowed"
 Requested Method Not allowed
```

How can i match the status_line to the value coming from CGI header?

Comment: Why are you mixing GGI.pm (removed from Core in favour of alternatives) with hand rolled CGI environment parsing (no, just no, no, no)?!

Answer (score 0):

Per this [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872574/perl-cgi-with-http-status-codes), you might try:

```
else
{
    $cgi->$header->status('405 Method Not Allowed')
    print $cgi->header('text/plain');
}
```

instead of your:

```
else
{
    print $cgi->header(
        -type=>'text/plain',
        -status=> '405 Method Not Allowed'
    );
 }
```